# What does error code 255 mean in Node.js child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am running php command from Node.js child_process.
In response it is showing error and throwing error with error code 255 because of which my script is breaking.

When i execute the command from terminal it works fine but in child_process it gives error.

```
async function decrypt(cipher){

    try {
        var terminal = require('child_process');
    var util     = require('util');
    var exec     = util.promisify(terminal.exec);
    var command  = "usr/bin/php " + basePath + "/decrypt.php '" + cipher +"'";

    return await exec(command);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.error(err.code +' | '+ err.message);
    }
}

module.exports = {
decrypt : decrypt
}




 { Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/nodejs/decrypt.php 'w5oFS8U4NGrleFHtptkmO+luDMw0z+fYrJ/onlj6fndIS/0QrWzOAsTN450VLZwR+GmDkyylybGJXUnx2VdeJQ=='



    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:281:12)

    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)

    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

    killed: false,

    code: 255,

    signal: null,

    cmd: '/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/nodejs/decrypt.php \'w5oFS8U4NGrleFHtptkmO+luDMw0z+fYrJ/onlj6fndIS/0QrWzOAsTN450VLZwR+GmDkyylybGJXUnx2VdeJQ==\'',

    stdout: '\t\n\n{"error":false,"decryptedText":"0324"}',

    stderr: '' }
```

Desired Output is : '{"error":false,"decryptedText":"0324"}'

Comment: Your `try/catch` doesn't work for Promise obj

Comment: Your PHP script might be returning a non-zero value, E.G. `-1`, which is a way to indicate an error occured and is why node thinks an error occurred even though your script did output the correct result. Check your PHP script for a statement like `exit -1;` or `die -1;`

Comment: @Luke.SWK try/catch works fine there. `await`ing a Promise throes an error if the Promise rejects.

Answer (score 0):

The error trace stack is more important than the error code.
[process exit code](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/doc/api/process.markdown#exit-codes)